# How to export data received by event in service worker to vue components?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, pusher

I am building a notification system with Pusher. Currently I have a service worker registered with Pusher and I can receive "notifications" sent from my backend, but I can only show them in console:

```js
importScripts("https://js.pusher.com/beams/service-worker.js");

PusherPushNotifications.onNotificationReceived = ({ pushEvent, payload }) => {
  pushEvent.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: payload.notification.icon,
      data: payload.data
    })
  );
  let notification = `Data recieved from notification ${payload.data.message}`;
  console.log(notification);
};
```

I want to export the variable "notifications" to my vue components to manipulate the information coming from the backend.

I have tried to export, but it didn't work.

The service worker is placed in the "public" folder.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Service workers communicate with a page only through messages.

```
function postMsg(message) {
  return self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clients) {
    clients.forEach(function(client) {
      client.postMessage(message)
    });
  });
}
```

And then you can listen to the message inside your page :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function (evt) {
  const message = evt.data

  if (message.type === 'notification') {
    doSomething(message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Broadcast Channel to be able to send the notifications to my vue components.

Create a new instance of BroadcastChannel. Name it (in this case, the name of the Broadcast Channel is 'sw-messages') and use the method "postMessage" to send the message:

```js
importScripts("https://js.pusher.com/beams/service-worker.js");
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');

PusherPushNotifications.onNotificationReceived = ({ pushEvent, payload }) => {
  pushEvent.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: payload.notification.icon,
      data: payload.data
    })
  );
  channel.postMessage({ title: payload.data});
};
```

In the vue component, I create (again) a new BroadcastChannel instance and then put an event handler, like this:

```js
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("sw-messages");
    channel.onmessage = function (event) {
      this.pushNotification = event.data;
      console.log(this.pushNotification.title);
    }
```